# Repeated replacement of a widget with a widget of equal size - how its done?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm currently working on a tkinter based python gui and in my program you are able to press a button and then the first widget is getting invisible and the other one ist displayed one the same position of the first one. After that you are able to switch back and the second widget disappears and the first one will be at the same position visible and so on...

My goal is that the two widgets get the same size if you are switching the wdigets and the user will not see any bigger/smaller widgets, but I'm not able to say how I can get there - may you can help me?

My tkinter window:

```
self.window = tkinter.Tk()
self.window.resizable(True, True)
self.window.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
self.window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
self.window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

My frame for the two widgets:

```
contentFrame = tkinter.Frame(master=self.window, bg="#FFF", highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
contentFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
contentFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
contentFrame.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
```

My first widget (red one):

```
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master=contentFrame, bg="#F00", highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
        canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

My second widget (blue one)

```
xmlEditor = tkinter.Text(master=contentFrame, bg="#00F", highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
```

And whats happening when change from red to blue one:

```
self.window.children["!frame2"].children["!canvas"].pack_forget()
self.window.children["!frame2"].children["!text"].pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

And whats happening when change from blue to red one:

```
self.window.children["!frame2"].children["!text"].pack_forget()
self.window.children["!frame2"].children["!canvas"].pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Look at the video [here](https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ahvfc1_FY97C11w8zXdPDPOonAY6?e=XUdX4n) to see the problem in action :)

Comment: It would be easier for us to give a good answer if you provided a [mcve]. Having disjointed blocks of code makes it difficult to reproduce the problem without a lot of work on our part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is use an intermediate frame which controls the size. Then, you can pack either the red or blue frame inside this frame.

Start by creating a subframe with the size you want. Lets say you want the area to be 500x500:

```
subframe = tk.Frame(contentFrame, width=500, height=500)
subframe.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Next, turn geometry propagation off so that the frame won't grow or shrink to fit its children:

```
subframe.pack_propagate(False)
```

Finally, put your red and blue frames inside this subframe:

```
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master=subframe, bg="#F00", highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
xmlEditor = tkinter.Text(master=subframe, bg="#00F", highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
```